# Select Min and Max value

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

I have a table called 'customers':

```
id | name    | age

1  | john    | 35        
2  | paul    | 22        
3  | ana     | 26   
4  | mark    | 19   
5  | jack    | 29
```

i want to select the name and max age, the name and min age... something like:

```
john 35 mark 19
```

is it possible?

Comment: What is your plan in case of a tie? Ex: 2 people are age 35?

Comment: lets just assume there's no tie

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The below query will give you the min and max on one row as requested. If there are multiple matches for min/max you will get multiple rows. Depending on the SQL engine you use, the syntax to limit to one row is different.

```
SELECT cMax.Name, cMax.Age, cMin.Name, cMin.Age
FROM customers cMin
JOIN customers cMax ON
    cMax.Age = (SELECT MAX(Age) FROM customers)
WHERE cMin.Age = (SELECT MIN(Age) FROM customers)
```

There are different types of joins (e.g. INNER, OUTER, CROSS); however, for your question it doesn't much matter which you use.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    select name, age from customers where age=(select max(age) from customers) union
 select name, age from customers where age=(select min(age) from customers)
```

Comment: union gives me the result in other row. can i make it in only one row?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it,

```
select name, age from customers
where age in (select max(age) 
from customers union select min (age)from customers)
```

Comment: union gives me the result in other row. can i make it in only one row?

Comment: there are many thing possible with SQL but there are limitations too, you can get this in one row but what will happen if there is a tie @dvo has asked the same in your question.

Comment: **select *  from
(select id,name, age from customers where age =(select  max(age) from customers)) as maxagecust,
(select id, name, age from customers where age =(select  min(age) from customers)) as minagecust**

Comment: @Mathaus posted the query as comments, but surely such queries are meant for homework assignment only

Answer (score 0):

If you want them on the same row:

```
select cmin.*, cmax.*
from (select name, age as minage
      from customers
      order by age asc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) cmin cross join
     (select name, age as maxage
      from customers
      order by age desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) cmax;
```

`fetch first 1 row only` is standard syntax for returning only the first row of the result set.  Some databases have bespoke syntax, such as `limit` or `select top (1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query to show MAX age:-
    `select * from customers where age=(select max(age) from customers);`

To show MIN age use the below Query:-
    `select * from customers where age=(select min(age) from customers);`

Answer (score -1):

You could use a [cross join](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cross-join/), which will put the two query ouputs next to one another. Building off Rodrigo's queries:

```
select
  max_cust.name,
  max_cust.age,
  min_cust.name,
  min_cust.age
from (select name, age from customers where age=(select max(age) from customers)) as max_cust
cross join (select name, age from customers where age=(select min(age) from customers)) as min_cust
```

It's maybe not the most performant but it gets the right shape. Be wary of cross joins when the tables don't have exactly 1 row, as it creates a cartesian product of the rows in the tables being joined.